# Finding the number that is multiple by two if we move the MSD to be the LSB

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which natural and decimal number meets the condition that if you move its left digit (Most significant) to be the right digit(least significant), the new number becomes 2 times the original number?

For example 2456 become 4562 but at this case 4562/2456 is not meets this condition.

I would like to see what the calculation method (not brute force!) is , and the final answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:calculus]?